# Merge Angular and Symfony

Tags: angular, symfony4

I have a [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) project (back-end) and an Angular project (front-end). I have to delete all the npm Angular back-end in order to put this in Symfony. I wish to know if there is a best way or particulars rules to follow. My idea is to create a back-end folder and a front-end folder and to put there my code.

Have others ideas?

Comment: Please try to improve the title of the question and the question itself. 
Explain what you are doing, and what you need to do, also the undesired effect. Check.: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have a font-end in angular and a js server in order to test it. But now I have the necessity to pass to php for the server. So I have to use Symphony, but I ask myself if there is some rules in order to put the front-end (Angular) in Symphony, because I see that Symphony uses twig. For instance in Sping and Maven there are some rules (because in each folder there is something of particular).

Comment: As Robert said, you are trying to mix two very different things. You cant mix Symphony and angular. Now what you can do is publish the angular build, usually "dist" folder inside the the symphony public folder. Now, in order to access whatever data you are working on symphony, create an public API, and consume it from angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular uses Js, Symfony uses PHP, you cant render Angular with Symfony

In order to render Angular in a server you need to use [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal).

If you want to serve your Angular App from a server  with PHP and Symfony then you only need to serve your index.html file from a Symfony view